# .net core web API,static file images not loading properly?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2

I have .net core web **API** PROJECT. I want to put some static images in this project.I have below code in start up file

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
// Add new mappings
provider.Mappings[".myapp"] = "application/x-msdownload";
provider.Mappings[".htm3"] = "text/html";
provider.Mappings[".image"] = "image/png";
provider.Mappings[".png"] = "image/png";
// Replace an existing mapping
provider.Mappings[".rtf"] = "application/x-msdownload";
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
   Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyStaticFiles")),
   RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles"),
   ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

when I run or deployed this web project, i have checked under it has StaticFiles folder has test.png
when I browse for test.tt/StaticFiles/test.png, or test.tt/wwwroot/StaticFiles/test.png or test.tt/wwwroot/StaticFiles/images/test.png

browser is not loading that image, it is displaying white page, where I check on network console of by F12,it is delivering response of type document and json.
My problem is image is not displaying, i have tried more images but not helpful.I am sure there is image,folder in my path.

can you tell how if I browse test.png,direct hitting path to get static file .net core WEB API images?

Answer (score 2):

By default, static files go into the `wwwroot` in your project root. Calling `app.UseStaticFiles()`, causes this directory to be served at the base path of the site, i.e. `/`. As such, a file like `wwwroot/images/test.png` would be available at `/images/test.png` (note: without the `wwwroot` part).

I'm not sure what in the world you're doing with the rest of this code here, but you're essentially adding an *additional* served directory at `[project root]/MyStaticFiles`, which will then be served at `/StaticFiles`. As such, first, test.png would have to actually be in `MyStaticFiles`, *not* `wwwroot`, and then you'd access by requesting `/StaticFiles/test.png`.

However, there's no need for this other directory. If you simply want to add some additional media types, you can do that via:

```
services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(o =>
{
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    provider.Mappings.Add(".myapp", "application/x-msdownload");
    // etc.
    o.ContentTypeProvider = provider;
});
```

And then just use:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Nothing else is required.

Comment: @chriss-pratt ,chriss-pratt ,thanks for this update. Actually I have tried the approach to use app.UseStatisFiles() and then move files into wwwroot/images/png, but now when i tried correct file with correct imge, and then i browse from my path, it is displaying white page, and not displaying image, where i check content type return is document, i think if it start returing type image then may be image get starting loading. i have tried exactly your solution , btw i am using .net core web api project.. can you please help me to sort it out?